# Remove text between two tags

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to remove some text between two tags [ & ]

```
[13:00:00]
```

I want to remove 13:00:00 from [] tags.
This number is not the same any time.
Its always a time of the day so, only Integer and : symbols.

Someone can help me?

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to say something. The time (13:00:00) was picked from a log file. Looks like that:

```
[10:56:49] [Client thread/ERROR]: Item entity 26367127 has no item?!
[10:57:25]  [Dbutant] misterflo13 : ils coute chere les enchent aura de feu et T2 du spawn??*
[10:57:35]  [Amateur] firebow ?.SkyLegend.?  : ouai 0
[10:57:38]  [Novice] iPasteque : ils sont gratuit me
[10:57:41]  [Novice] iPasteque : ils sont gratuit mec *
[10:57:46]  [Dbutant] misterflo13 : on ma dit k'ils etait payent :o
[10:57:57]  [Novice] iPasteque : on t'a mytho alors
```

Ignore the other text I juste want to remove the time between [ & ] (need to looks like []. The time between [ & ] is updated every second.

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: I updated mine for multiline too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another possibility using `Regex`:

```
Public Function ReplaceTime(ByVal Input As String) As String
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(Input, "(\[)(\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}(\:\d{1,2})?)(\])(.+)")
    Return m.Groups(1).Value & m.Groups(4).Value & m.Groups(5).Value
End Function
```

It's more of a readability nightmare but it's efficient and it takes only the brackets containing a time value.

I also took the liberty of making it match for example `13:47` as well as `13:47:12`.

Test: http://ideone.com/yogWfD

**(EDIT) Multiline example:**

You can combine this with `File.ReadAllLines()` (if that's what you prefer) and a `For` loop to get the replacement done.

```
Public Function ReplaceTimeMultiline(ByVal TextLines() As String) As String
    For x = 0 To TextLines.Length - 1
        TextLines(x) = ReplaceTime(TextLines(x))
    Next
    Return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, TextLines)
End Function
```

Above code usage:

```
Dim FinalT As String = ReplaceTimeMultiline(File.ReadAllLines(<file path here>))
```

---

**Another multiline example:**

```
Public Function ReplaceTimeMultiline(ByVal Input As String) As String
    Dim ReturnString As String = ""
    Dim Parts() As String = Input.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    For x = 0 To Parts.Length - 1
        ReturnString &= ReplaceTime(Parts(x)) & If(x < (Parts.Length - 1), Environment.NewLine, "")
    Next
    Return ReturnString
End Function
```

Multiline test: http://ideone.com/nKZQHm

Comment: This is working, but only for 1 line. This is show only the first line of the text file.

Comment: doesn't work. The text is always random so I can't write for exemple, "[13:11:34] test" in my code cuz Test came randomlly.

Comment: @ZitroTech What do you mean? I don't understand your comment. What is not working?

Comment: @ZitroTech I know the text is random, _you don't need_ to hardcode the strings like I did in my example. To use this you just do `ReplaceTimeMultiline(<input string here>)`. So `[13:11:34] test` would become `[] test`. This will work with any random string that you get from the log.

Comment: If you want to read an entire file (log) you could do for example: `ReplaceTimeMultiline(IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\logs\log.txt"))` - or wherever your log is located.

Comment: This is what I have in my code: Dim FinalT As String = ReplaceTimeMultiline(File.ReadAllLines(LogsPath))                                              LogsPath As String                                                                                      Its tell me then I can't covert String() to String

Comment: @ZitroTech `File.ReadAllLines()` creates an _array_ of strings. Use `File.ReadAllText()` instead, **OR even better** see my new edit.

Comment: Actually you can have both my `ReplaceTimeMultiline()` methods in your project if you'd like. Your app will automatically pick the one that fits your input best. One function takes a `String()` (such as `File.ReadAllLines`), and the other function takes a `String` (such as `File.ReadAllText` or `Dim s As String`).

Comment: @ZitroTech you've written my code incorrectly. The code in the loop should be: `ReturnString &= ReplaceTime(Parts(x)) & ...`, _**NOT:**_ `ReturnString &= ReplaceTimeMultiline(Parts(x)) & ...`

Comment: You must include the original `ReplaceTime()` function (the code in the top of my answer) for the `ReplaceTimeMultiline()` functions to work.

Comment: Also, be sure to declare `ReturnString` like this: `Dim ReturnString As String = ""`. I forgot to add the `= ""` part to the code, it would have caused a NullReferenceException.

Comment: See again... Sorry im a begineer :(   https://mega.nz/#!8xpUxA7I!M6rPmy_CZfJJ-hGh50MEVT-XdaqgsjudfKWCfBLdUrE

Comment: No its okay, I use something else to open the file and its working !!! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @ZitroTech Still, `File.ReadAllLines()` creates an array of strings (that is, a list of multiple strings). ReadAllLines creates _multiple_ strings, but the function only takes _one_ string. So for that matter you'd use `File.ReadAllText()` or something.

Comment: Though, the second code block in my post takes an array of string (which is defined as `String()`), so that _would_ work with `File.ReadAllLines()` but not `File.ReadAllText()`. **Refer to the MSDN documentation: [File.ReadAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) - [File.ReadAllText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) - [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx).** - It's a great place to look when there's something you're wondering about. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your log has specific format. And you seem want to get rid of the time and keep all other information. Ok - read in comments

I didn't test it but it should work

```
' Read log
Dim logLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("File_path")
If logLines.Length = 0 Then Return
' prepare array to fill sliced data
Dim lines(logLines.Length - 1) As String

For i As Integer = 0 To logLines.Count - 1
    ' just cut off time part and add empty brackets for each line
    lines(i) = "[]" & logLines(i).Substring(10)
Next
```

What you see above - if you know that your file comes in certain format, just use position in the string where to cut it off.

> Note: Code above can be done in 1 line using LINQ

If you want to actually get the data out of it, use `IndexOf`. Since you looking for first occurrence of "[" or "]", just use start index "0"

```
' get position of open bracket in string
Dim openBracketPos As Integer = myString.IndexOf("[", 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
' get position of close bracket in string
Dim closeBracketPos As Integer = myString.IndexOf("]", 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

' get string between open and close bracket
Dim data As String = myString.Substring(openBracketPos + 1, closeBracketPos - 1)
```

Comment: The log is alerady readed by a StreamReader. I convert to String. Does I do your code anyway? (to read the log file) And I don't want to get the data between [ & ] but remove it.

Comment: @ZitroTech You don't need to use `StreamReader`. `File.ReadAllLines` already wraps all of it for you. It is just much easier to use. You load your array and convert your data into format you want to see. It is going to be way too complex **[unnecessarily]** to read some characters and skip writing them if this is date. Look, I just programmed your whole thing in 6 lines and I can make it 3 lines

Comment: I will try with File.ReadAllLines, but I will need to convert a String() to String and I don't know how...

Comment: @ZitroTech : Use `File.ReadAllText()` and you will get it as a String: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to remove numeric strings in the format of 99:99:99 that appear inside [], I would do:

//assuming you want to replace the [......] numeric string with an empty []. Should you want to completely remove the tag, just replace with string.Empty

Here's a *demo* (in C#, not VB, but you get the point (you need the regex, not the syntax anyway)

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>
    {
        "[13:00:00]",
        "[4:5:0]",
        "[5d2hu2d]",
        "[1:1:1000]",
        "[1:00:00]",
        "[512341]"
    };

    string s = string.Join("\n", list);
    Console.WriteLine("Original input string:");
    Console.WriteLine(s);

    Regex r = new Regex(@"\[\d{1,2}?:\d{1,2}?:\d{1,2}?\]");
    foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a match.", m.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("String with occurrences replaced with an empty string:");
    Console.WriteLine(r.Replace(s, string.Empty).Trim());
```

[image]